# Recover deleted text messages that are still on old iPhone

Tags: iphone, messages, data-recovery

I've accidentally deleted some text messages on my iPhone. These messages are still on my old iPhone which has not connected to the internet for a long time, so they haven't been deleted when syncing.

Because my old iPhone hasn't been used in a while, there are a lot of messages on the new phone that the old phone doesn't have.

How can I recover the messages that are on my old phone?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify  the status of the device's connections:  cellular and WiFi.  However, you want to ensure that they are not connected in case you have your AppleID signed in on the device; you don't want messages to sync as they'll be deleted.

Before you turn it on, make sure it can't connect.  Remove the SIM if necessary.  As for WiFi, take it out of range of the network(s) you've used previously.  If that's not possible, temporarily change your WiFi password (that's the simplest method).  Once logged in, you can go to *Airplane Mode* and put everything back (i.e. WiFi password).  The idea is not allow your phone the slightest opportunity to sync.

Once you are certain it's disconnected, so there's no chance of syncing with the cloud, open iMessage.  There's no function to export messages, however you can take screenshots or forward them as mail messages.

- Screenshots can be saved and synced via USB using Finder on a Mac or iTunes in Windows.
- If you forward them as email messages, they will queue up in your outgoing mail folder until you connect to a network; they will all send at once.

Comment: Yes, the device hasn't connected to any networks since the deletion happened and isn't going to - there's no SIM and it's out of range of any saved WiFi networks. So the best way is to restore messages one-by-one by forwarding them as email? I was hoping there was a way to restore them as iMessage entries on my current phone.

Comment: There's no export or save in iMessage.  You can either screenshot the messages for forward them to an email/message recipient.

Comment: There are 3rd-party utilities like iMazing and IExplorer that can backup an iPhone to a Mac or PC and then allow you to get at the contents easily. I think that you could get the messages out of iMessage. I have iMazing but have never needed to extract messages, but I *believe* this is possible, and they have a free trial.